# LibGDX + gdx-freetype + BlueStacks

Tags: android, libgdx, bluestacks

I have app correctly working on real android devices and on desktop. Homever when i'm trying to launch it on BlueStacks emulator i got some problems.  Already downloaded and added to libs .so file from here http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn/tags/0.9.6/extensions/gdx-freetype/libs/linux32/

but still:

```
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 9
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx-freetype' for target: Linux, 32-bit
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:110)
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeType.initFreeType(FreeType.java:541)
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.<init>(FreeTypeFontGenerator.java:64)
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.axl.where.test.create(test.java:153)
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:334)
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1356)
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gdx-freetype: findLibrary returned null
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     at    com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:106)
11-08 21:14:10.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1378):     ... 6 more
```

Any ideas ? LibGDX 0.9.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a x86 folder in your libs directory (along the armeabi ones), and copy this file on it:

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/dist/extensions/gdx-freetype/x86/

also, you are using the v0.9.6 files o.O use the nightlies:

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/dist/extensions/gdx-freetype/

Comment: There were indeed two problems, one extension was old and second that x86 dir missing. Thanks!